# In Play Framework 2, how do I pass in an external value for form validators to use?

Tags: validation, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

This can't be too uncommon.  I want to get a "fullPathAndFileName" value, that's not in my form, into a validator.

In one of my controllers I have a file renaming action:

```
def renameAction(fullPathAndFileName: String) = Action { implicit request =>
  val newRenameForm = renameForm.bindFromRequest()
  newRenameForm.fold(
    hasErrors = { form =>
      Redirect(routes.TestApp.renderFormAction(fullPathAndFileName)).flashing("error" -> "New filename must be unused and cannot be empty.")
    },
    success = { newFileName =>
      ...
```

Here's my validator:

```
private val renameForm: Form[String] = Form("newFileName" -> nonEmptyText.verifying({txt => dupeNotFound(txt)}))

private def dupeNotFound(newFileName: String) = { !Asset.findAsset(replaceFileNameOfAsset(fullPathAndFileName, newFileName)) }
```

So this code won't compile, because fullPathAndFileName is not defined.  How can I let the validator use that value?

Comment: Make renameForm a function that takes a String as argument and returns a Form[String], then just pass fullPathAndFileName to it. Then, of course, make sure that dupeNotFound also gets the passed in string so it can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as answer instead of just commenting...anyway, this should work if I understand things correctly...

```
val newRenameForm = renameForm(fullPathAndFileName).bindFromRequest()
```

And the validator...

```
private val renameForm: (String) => Form[String] = (fullPathAndFileName: String) => Form("newFileName" -> nonEmptyText.verifying({txt => dupeNotFound(fullPathAndFileName,txt)}))

private def dupeNotFound(fullPathAndFileName: String, newFileName: String) = { !Asset.findAsset(replaceFileNameOfAsset(fullPathAndFileName, newFileName)) }
```

Comment: Awesome assistance, and your solution works great.  I need to consult with my neurologist on how to fix my brain to think more "functionally".  Just a small correction to your code though, based on my actual implementation: `private val renameForm: (String) => Form[String] = (fullPathAndFileName: String) => Form( ...`    ... the type has to be changed to a functional type.  Will try to edit your answer.